# Why does the method of a struct that does not read/write its contents still cause a race case?

Tags: go, struct, concurrency, race-condition, goroutine

From [the Dave Cheney Blog](http://dave.cheney.net/2015/11/18/wednesday-pop-quiz-spot-the-race), the following code apparently causes a race case that can be resolved merely by changing `func (RPC) version() int` to `func (*RPC) version() int` :

```
package main

import (
        "fmt"
        "time"
)

type RPC struct {
        result int
        done   chan struct{}
}

func (rpc *RPC) compute() {
        time.Sleep(time.Second) // strenuous computation intensifies
        rpc.result = 42
        close(rpc.done)
}

func (RPC) version() int {
        return 1 // never going to need to change this
}

func main() {
        rpc := &RPC{done: make(chan struct{})}

        go rpc.compute()         // kick off computation in the background
        version := rpc.version() // grab some other information while we're waiting
        <-rpc.done               // wait for computation to finish
        result := rpc.result

        fmt.Printf("RPC computation complete, result: %d, version: %d\n", result, version)
}
```

After looking over the code a few times, I was having a hard time believing that the code had a race case. However, when running with --race, it claims that there was a write at `rpc.result=42` and a previous read at `version := rpc.version()`. I understand the write, since the goroutine changes the value of `rpc.result`, but what about the read? Where in the `version()` method does the read occur? It does not touch any of the values of rpc, just returning 1.

I would like to understand the following:

1) Why is that particular line considered a read on the rpc struct?

2) Why would changing `RPC` to `*RPC` resolve the race case?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When you have a method with value receiver like this:

```
func (RPC) version() int {
    return 1 // never going to need to change this
}
```

And you call this method:

```
version := rpc.version() // grab some other information while we're waiting
```

A copy has to be made from the value `rpc`, which will be passed to the method (used as the receiver value).

So while one goroutine `go rpc.compute()` is running and is modifying the `rpc` struct value (`rpc.result = 42`), the main goroutine is making a copy of the whole `rpc` struct value. There! It's a race.

When you modify the receiver type to pointer:

```
func (*RPC) version() int {
    return 1 // never going to need to change this
}
```

And you call this method:

```
version := rpc.version() // grab some other information while we're waiting
```

This is a shorthand for

```
version := (&rpc).version()
```

This passes the address of the `rpc` value to `RPC.version()`, it uses only the pointer as the receiver, so no copy is made of the `rpc` struct value. And since nothing from the struct is used / read in `RPC.version()`, there is no race.

**Note:**

Note that if `RPC.version()` would read the `RPC.result` field, it would also be a race, as one goroutine modifies it while the main goroutine would read it:

```
func (rpc *RPC) version() int {
    return rpc.result // RACE!
}
```

**Note #2:**

Also note that if `RPC.version()` would read another field of `RPC` which is not modified in `RPC.compute()`, that would not be a race, e.g.:

```
type RPC struct {
    result int
    done   chan struct{}
    dummy  int
}

func (rpc *RPC) version() int {
    return rpc.dummy // Not a race
}
```