# Race condition. Cannot figure out why

Tags: go, pointers, struct, race-condition

A Race Condition occures when i'am running my code. It is a simple implementation of a concurrent safe storage. The Race Condition disappears when i change the reciever in get() method to `(p *storageType)`. I'm confused. I need someone who could explain to me such a behaivior.

```
package main

type storageType struct {
    fc    chan func()
    value int
}

func newStorage() *storageType {
    p := storageType{
        fc: make(chan func()),
    }
    go p.run()
    return &p
}

func (p storageType) run() {
    for {
        (<-p.fc)()
    }
}

func (p *storageType) set(s int) {
    p.fc <- func() {
        p.value = s
    }
}

func (p storageType) get() int {
    res := make(chan int)
    p.fc <- func() {
        res <- p.value
    }
    return <-res
}

func main() {

    storage := newStorage()

    for i := 0; i < 1000; i++ {
        go storage.set(i)
        go storage.get()
    }
}
```

Comment: What machine / os / go version ?   I tried 8-core / macos / go1.10; and 16-core / macos / go1.14; it appears to work fine on those.

Comment: linux, go1.16.3, 64bit

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In `main()` the `storage` variable is of type `*storageType`. If `storageType.Get()` has value receiver, then `storage.get()` means `(*storage).get()`.

The `get()` call has `storageType` as the reciver, so the `storage` pointer variable has to be dereferenced to make a copy (that will be used as the receiver value). This copying means the value of the pointed `storageType` struct must be read. But this read is not synchronized with the `run()` method which reads and writes the struct (its `value` field).

If you change the receiver of `get()` to be a pointer (of type `*storageType`), then the receiver again will be a copy, but this time it will be a copy of the pointer, not the pointed struct. So no unsynchronized read of the struct happens.

See possible duplicate: [Why does the method of a struct that does not read/write its contents still cause a race case?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39042074/why-does-the-method-of-a-struct-that-does-not-read-write-its-contents-still-caus/39042317#39042317)

Comment: i get it now! Thanx a lot!

Answer (score -1):

First one: your `main` function doesn't wait for all goroutines to finish. All goroutines are forced to return when `main` does.

Look into using a [`sync.WaitGroup`](https://golang.org/pkg/sync/#WaitGroup)